# How to implement grounding into this electrical circuit?

Tags: dc, ground, grounding

I'm trying to make some tutorials but I have no idea what should I do when I see the term ground (GND). Here is an example:

[image: circuit example]

I want to know how I build the GND part. Where I connect it? Also, if it's a 12 volt application it's very unlikely to kill anyone, is it?

Comment: What is the power source? A battery or plug-in? Either way, "GND" will be the negative terminal or wire.

Comment: The power source is a battery.

Comment: Not meaning to be unkind, but judging from the level of sophistication of your questions, your level of expertise hardly seems adequate for you to author a meaningful - not to mention **safe** - tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

In most electronics and electrical circuits, "Ground" or "GND" is just the point in the circuit that we choose to call "zero volts", and use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit - it is where we put the black meter lead.

Very often, "GND" is the most negative terminal of the power supply, but if the designer chooses, may be the positive terminal, or perhaps the mid-point of the power supply.

There is no "GND" part, and "Ground" has no special or magical properties.

In AC power distribution, and in some radio antenna systems, "Ground" does indicate a connection to the earth, but that clearly doesn't apply in portable battery-operated circuits.

Comment: So I can ignore that part entirely for this small project? And what do you mean by 'zero volts' how can there be no voltage if it's part of the circuit?

Comment: @Tamás You need a voltage difference to get current to flow.

Comment: If you connect an LED to a battery which part is the ground? I'll be honest, when it comes to grounding I imagine a thick metal wire leaving the circuit and entering the Earth's crust in half a meter deep.

Comment: The "ground" is the battery negative (-) terminal.

Comment: @Tamás, when you have a battery, say 12V, there are two leads, correct? You have surely seen the nomenclature for these terminals being `positive` and `negative`, right? For the simplest of applications, the `positive` terminal is taken with respect to the `negative` terminal which becomes your `ground`. Just think that there is a 12V `potential difference` across those two terminals. The fact that you select the `negative` terminal as your `ground` is arbitrary.

Comment: In most cases, I think it would be better to use the terms "reference" or "common", than "ground", but the use of "ground" for the "zero volts" reference point is so firmly embedded in tradition that my opinion won't change this (mis)use.  Just consider "ground" as the place you put your black meter lead when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.